# set width to dropdown and adjust text within size as per width

Tags: html, html-select

```
.option100{
    width:100px !important;
} 

<select id="fieldOfInterestSelect" name="fieldOfInterest" class="form-control" required=""><option value="-1">SELECT ONE</option><option value="4893" class="option100">Actual(R)rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option><option value="4891" class="option100">Customerrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option><option value="4892" class="option100">Daterrrrrrr</option><option value="4894" class="option100">Forecast(R)RRRRRR</option></select>
```

Even though I have fixed size of option , it is not applied.
If text is large then option box get expanded to length of text.

Comment: it is not really clear what you want to achieve - it looks quite normal:https://jsfiddle.net/akvs3jzm/

Comment: It's like: If a text is too large that can't fit in single line for  width:100px , it should adjust in two or more  lines. Here in my case ;option' size is increasing automatically .

Comment: Anyone can help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution by trying in various ways. Best way is to trim text and ad full text on 'title'. [2] Another solution that works, use UL LI structure.
I have implemented and works fine for me. That also solves another problem of classes getting overriden by default class.